# How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to the controller

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I need to pass and receive two parameters to the state I want to transit to using `ui-sref` of ui-router.

Something like using the link below for transitioning the state to `home` with `foo` and `bar` parameters:

```
<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal', bar: 'barVal'})">Go to home state with foo and bar parameters </a>
```

Receiving `foo` and `bar` values in a controller:

```
app.controller('SomeController', function($scope, $stateParam) {
  //..
  var foo = $stateParam.foo; //getting fooVal
  var bar = $stateParam.bar; //getting barVal
  //..
});
```

I get `undefined` for `$stateParam` in the controller.

Could somebody help me understand how to get it done?

**Edit:**

```
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'MainRootCtrl'

    },

    'A@home': {
      templateUrl: 'a.html',
      controller: 'MainCtrl'
    },

    'B@home': {
      templateUrl: 'b.html',
      controller: 'SomeController'
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: You need to have them set up in your routes as well. ex:-  `url:'.../home/:foo/:bar`

Comment: @PSL: Could you just give a small example here? Thanks.

Comment: @PSL: Thanks PSL, is there any other way I could have those parameters with their values in a controller?

Comment: Do `'/:foo/:bar': {` in your blank route or you can set up as querystring as well.

Answer (score 547, accepted):

I've created an [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview) to show how to. Updated `state` definition would be:

```
  $stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/:foo?bar',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
          controller: 'MainRootCtrl'

        },
        ...
      }
```

And this would be the controller:

```
.controller('MainRootCtrl', function($scope, $state, $stateParams) {
    //..
    var foo = $stateParams.foo; //getting fooVal
    var bar = $stateParams.bar; //getting barVal
    //..
    $scope.state = $state.current
    $scope.params = $stateParams; 
})
```

What we can see is that the state home now has url defined as:

```
url: '/:foo?bar',
```

which means, that the params in url are expected as

```
/fooVal?bar=barValue
```

These two links will correctly pass arguments into the controller:

```
<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal1', bar: 'barVal1'})">
<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal2', bar: 'barVal2'})">
```

Also, the controller does consume `$stateParams` instead of `$stateParam`.

Link to doc:

- [URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)

You can check it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview)

#### `params : {}`

There is also *new*, more granular setting *`params : {}`*. As we've already seen, we can declare parameters as part of **`url`**. But with `params : {}` configuration - we can extend this definition or even introduce paramters which are not part of the url:

```
.state('other', {
    url: '/other/:foo?bar',
    params: { 
        // here we define default value for foo
        // we also set squash to false, to force injecting
        // even the default value into url
        foo: {
          value: 'defaultValue',
          squash: false,
        },
        // this parameter is now array
        // we can pass more items, and expect them as []
        bar : { 
          array : true,
        },
        // this param is not part of url
        // it could be passed with $state.go or ui-sref 
        hiddenParam: 'YES',
      },
    ...
```

Settings available for params are described in the documentation of the [$stateProvider](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider)

Below is just an extract

- **value - {object|function=}**: specifies the default value for this parameter. This implicitly sets this parameter as optional...
- **array - {boolean=}:** (default: false) If true, the param value will be treated as an array of values.
- **squash - {bool|string=}:** squash configures how a default parameter value is represented in the URL when the current parameter value is the same as the default value.

We can call these params this way:

```
// hidden param cannot be passed via url
<a href="#/other/fooVal?bar=1&amp;bar=2">
// default foo is skipped
<a ui-sref="other({bar: [4,5]})">
```

Check it in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/r2JhV4PcYpKJdBCwHIWS?p=preview)

Comment: Great answer but what if I want to do something like this - <a ui-sref="profile.dashboard({aintUserId : [{{ibusUser.icdoUser.idoUser.userId}}] })"> this does not work. How can I get it to work?

Comment: @Radim, can you take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41429784/ui-sref-of-angular-ui-router-not-working-as-expected and help me a bit

Comment: You can also have a url like this: `url: "/:id?foo&bar"`

Answer (score 111):

You don't necessarily need to have the parameters inside the URL.

For instance, with:

```
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
  url: '/',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: 'home.html',
      controller: 'MainRootCtrl'

    },
  },
  params: {
    foo: null,
    bar: null
  }
})
```

You will be able to send parameters to the state, using either:

```
$state.go('home', {foo: true, bar: 1});
// or
<a ui-sref="home({foo: true, bar: 1})">Go!</a>
```

Of course, if you reload the page once on the `home` state, you will loose the state parameters, as they are not stored anywhere.

A full description of this behavior is documented [here](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$stateProvider), under the `params` row in the `state(name, stateConfig)` section.

Answer (score 31):

You simply misspelled `$stateParam`, it should be `$stateParams` (with an s). That's why you get undefined ;)

Comment: Generally this should go as a comment in the question. But anyway +1 for the efforts taken in reading the question and understanding the problem :)