# ui-sref and variable state parameter names

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I want to render a link such as:

`<a ui-sref="myState({myKey: 'my variable type value'})">`

where state name `myState` and key `myKey` are variables.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Yes you need to register myKey in route.. But wait did you mean `myKey` is actually derived dynamically?

Comment: Yes I want `myKey` to be an actual scope variable eg set in the `link ` method.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found myself in the same situation, I couldn't acomplish that as well, try to move your code using ng-click and inside of your ng-click function use a [$stage.go](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state) and pass the parameters there, something like:

```
$scope.clickHandler = function(param){
    $state.go('state.name',{myKey:param});
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I would REALLY like to avoid that, although I may not have a choice in the matter.

Comment: ui-router doesn't currently support dynamic ui-srefs.  https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395

Comment: sadly this method doesn't generate a valid href link

Answer (score 1):

Dynamic `ui-sref` is not supported, but I found an advice on using the generation of the link with [the href method of the $state service](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/395#issuecomment-24032104):

```
<a href="{{ctrl.url(myState, myKey)}}>

url = function(myState, myKey) {
    return $state.href(myState, {myKey: 'my variable type value'});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually I found a solution, so hopefully it will still help someone.

```html
<li ng-repeat="item in array" ui-sref="stateName({param:{{item.key}}})">
     Some content
</li>
```

In my case I am using **ui-router 1.0.15**, so not sure if it will work with something older than v1.0.x

Answer (score 0):

[How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller)

Similar question was asked here. His solution was to set up a state that does the routing and you pass params to that state through ui-sref that triggers the desired URL

Answer (score -1):

document({ id: document.id})

If your state is document/:id

Answer (score -1):

I think the simplest solution is

```
<button ui-sref="myState({mykey:vm.key})"> Link </button>
```

where vm.key is the value being passed from the controller. This avoids extra javascript as used in the answer for this. Its very similar to the accepted answer but the variable is used into the html tag as is, without creating a handler.

Comment: what's myState here?