# Angular UI-router not displayig the view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I try to make a nested views with UI-Router, but got stuck with fact that my view not displaying, though XHR in console indicates correct path and success in loading.The URL also updated as expected.

Here's the related code:

```
         .state('teams.tasks', {
             url: '/:teamID',
             templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
             controller: "itemsCtrl"
         })

         .state('items', {
             url: '/items',
             templateUrl: 'views/items.html',
             controller: "itemsCtrl"
         })
```

and in the view:

```
    <a ui-sref=".teams({ id: team.id })" class="h4 media-heading">{{ team.name }}</a>
```

The idea is — when i click this link i go to /teams/teamname, where teamname is created dynamically in the controller. The link url generates properly, but i don't see the related partial.

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: Edited! Sorry for that.

Comment: ui-sref="teams({ id: team.id })" ??  Try it ui-sref="teams.tasks"

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not what i want to. This {id team.id) is generated dynamically in the controller, so it is unique for all of the items.

Thing is — link is generated properly, but no view is loaded!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you forgot ui-view

For example :

```
<div ui-view ></div>
```

You need to add the ui-view in your target container

Comment: I have ui-view in my index.html and all partials go inside it.

Comment: You were right! Thank you so much! — Kinda tricky thing that i have to have two ui-views