# AngularFire - Error: Could not resolve '#/tabpost' from state 'tabdash'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, angularfire

Maybe my issue seems easy to resolve, but I've this problem since a lot of hours : When I'm in my dashboard, all data of my Firebase database are visible (With Ng-repeat).
But I can't found a solution for choose one specific item and see his details in another page.

I've test this method above and I've this error "Error: Could not resolve '#/tabpost' from state 'tabdash".

This is the HTML (This is an example) :

```
<div ng-repeat="post in posts">

<div class="card" ui-sref="#/post/{id}">
<h1>{{post.title}}</h1>
<p>{{post.content}}</p>
</div>

</div>
```

In App JS :

```
  .state('tabpost', {
  url: 'tabpost/id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
  })
```

In Service JS (in Post Factory) :

```
 myApp.factory("Post", ["$firebaseArray", "$firebaseObject", function($firebaseArray, $firebaseObject) {
var postRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts/');
var userRef = new Firebase('https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Users/');
var posts = $firebaseArray(postRef);

     var Post = {

         all: posts,

         get: function (postKey){
          var postId = $firebaseObject(postRef);
                return $firebaseObject(eventRef.child('Posts').child(postId).child(userid));

              }
            ,
        add: function (post){
          var postId = $firebaseArray(postRef, userRef);
          event.userid = userRef.getAuth();
                return postId.$add(post);
              }
       }
       return Post;

}]);
```

My PostCtrl :

```
myApp.controller('PostCtrl', ['$ionicFrostedDelegate', '$ionicScrollDelegate','$state','$scope', 'Post', 'Auth', '$firebaseObject', '$firebaseArray', '$routeParams', function($ionicFrostedDelegate, $ionicScrollDelegate, $state,$scope, Post, Auth, $firebaseObject, $firebaseArray, $routeParams) {

  var PostRef = new Firebase("https://myApp.firebaseio.com/Posts");

var id = $routeParams.id; //get the id from url, $routeParams is injected in controller

  $state.go('tabpost', {
    id: $scope.id
  });

  $scope.posts = Post.get(id); //call get() method of Post with the id retrieved

  $scope.post = {'title': '', 'content': ''};

  $scope.auth = Auth;
```

PS : It took 3 days and night to try a bunch of tutorials mostly obsolete , and I am sure that the solution can not be that simple.

I already posted three similar issues yesterday and later but each of the proposed solutions have not worked . I would be immensely grateful to the person who would help me out of this impasse .

I still have a little trouble with jsFiddle promised I would learn to use it once I would have solved this problem.

Thank you for giving me time

Comment: Can you post more of your `app.js` or create a codepen/plunker/some code example? If you are using Ionic's `ui-router` then you should be using `$stateParams`, not `$routeParams`, and your url in your state definition should be like this `url: 'tabpost/:id'` (note the colon before id). See [this blog](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-5-master-detail-pattern/) for more info.

Comment: Thanks , I will test it and I come back. U want all my routeprovider ?

Comment: `ui-sref="#/post/{id}"`  is not correct. You need to pass in the state name, not a hash, for ex  `<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal1', bar: 'barVal1'})">`  ..  See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/25647714/1516309

Comment: Now this is correct : ui-sref="post({title: '', content: ''})" ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to prefix your variable names with a colon in your state's URL. Your ui-router state should be

```
 .state('tabpost', {
  url: 'tabpost/:id',
  templateUrl: 'templates/tab-post.html',
  controller: 'PostCtrl'
  });
```

and you should link to it like

```
<div class="card" ui-sref="tabpost/{id}">
```

Comment: I've try but I have the same error : Error: Could not resolve 'tabpost/{id}' from state 'tabdash'

Comment: look at the DOM in your console, is {id} actually getting injected or is it remaining as the string "{id}"?

Comment: Always the string id ..

Comment: shouldn't it be {{id}} not {id} ?

Comment: When I use {{id}} , the error become : Error: Could not resolve 'tabpost/' from state 'tabdash'

Comment: I have the sensation the problem come of Controller or Service. I think the ID is not retrieved ...