# Angularjs ui-sref is there a way to pass a string between some pages

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use ui-router and ui-sref.

first page

```
<a id="XXX" ui-sref="app.page2">goto second page</a>
```

second page

```
<a ui-sref="app.page3">goto third page</a>
```

third page template or controller
Here I should receive id XXX form button on the first page

Is there a way to pass a string between 3 pages?

Comment: The answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass values through the ui-router this way:

```
<a ui-sref="app.page3({value: {{theValue}} })">goto third page</a>
```

This will work if you have theValue in scope. Replace the value to be passed along to suit your needs.

In your controller you can get the value through `$state`, like this: `$state.params.value`.

Comment: this works! Just in state need to be added url: /page3?value

Answer (score 0):

If the value is static then you should be able to store this value in the associated controller. Create an angular service to hold the value you need between the pages:

`https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services

Then use the value on your third page.

Comment: This way is also possible. I think using a mix of Services providing complex data and State-Parameters to retrieve specific data needed is the way to go. Example: Store data with some id in Service and pass the id via Stateparams to your state.