# Angular ui-router: accessing $stateParams on reload

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, parameter-passing, state

In my Angular app, I have this route structure:

```
.state('mapping', {
    url: '/mapping',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/mapping.html',
    controller: 'MapCtrl as map',
    abstract: true,
    authenticate: true
})
.state('mapping.all', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/all.html',
    authenticate: true
})
.state('mapping.project', {
    url: '/:projectName',
    controller: 'ProjectCtrl as proj',
    templateUrl: 'app/components/mapping/partials/project.html',
    authenticate: true
})
```

The intended functionality is that when a user access `'mapping.project'` the application will load all relevant information relative to that project using a `projectID` variable which is passed (invisibly) through `$stateParams` using `ui-sref`:

```
ui-sref="mapping.project({projectId: project.id, projectName: project.name})"
```

However this results in an unwanted behavior: when a user reloads the page when already on the `'mapping.project'` state, nothing will be loaded because no `$stateParams` were effectively passed.

What would be the best way to get `projectId` on reload (*and* make sure my controller gets initiated again) without showing it on the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, if we want our params to survive a page reload (or open in a new tab/window) they simply *must* be part of the URL. So the way to do this is to extend the URL definition with `projectId`:

```
.state('mapping.project', {
    url: '/:projectName?projectId',
    ...
})
```

that will add that `projectId` as "query string param". Another option is *params* nesting

```
.state('mapping.project', {
    url: '/:projectName/:projectId',
    ...
})
```

Check also this: [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647454/1679310)

Comment: I did not know that, I thought passing $stateParams invisibly would work as intended. Thank you!

Comment: It simply could not, because it is passing parameters via Javascript inside of our SPA. Reload or open in a new window === just url parts remain