# AngularJS UI-Router navigate without removing query params

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router to manage the states of my application, and I have query params where I save some data about the application.

I'm using `ui-sref` no navigate to another state, but this removes the query params from the URL. Is there any way to change the state of the application without removing the query params?

Answer (score 3):

There is an option `{location : false}` - check the doc:

#### [go(to, params, options)](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.state.$state)

> ...
>   **`Options`** object. The options are:
>
> - `location - {boolean=true|string=}` - If true will update the url in the location bar, if false will not. If string, must be "replace",
>     which will update url and also replace last history record.
> - `inherit - {boolean=true}`, If true will inherit url parameters from current url.
> - `relative - {object=$state.$current}`, When transitioning with relative path (e.g '^'), defines which state to be relative from.
> - `notify - {boolean=true}`, If true will broadcast $stateChangeStart and $stateChangeSuccess events.
> - `reload` (v0.2.5) - `{boolean=false}`, If true will force transition even if the state or params have not changed, aka a reload of the same
>     state. It differs from reloadOnSearch because you'd use this when you
>     want to force a reload when everything is the same, including search
>     params.

But I would rather keep such parameters as part of target state `url`:

- [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25647454/1679310)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment. But I do want to url to be replaced, but just just the path part, not the query params

Comment: As I said, there is solution "keep such parameters as part of target state"... so I would suggest to extend target state, and pass these params as well. That would be the native UI-Router solution... Does it help? It could even be driven by state inheritance, so these params are defined by parent and child just profit from it...

Comment: Thanks, I ended up passing the params inside the ui-sref (`ui-sref="secondPage({param1: value1})"`) I just thought maybe there is an easier way just to leave the query params as they are.