# How to navigate to a state inside a custom directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying my hand in writing custom directives and ran into a problem.

> I'm implementing a **ANCHOR BUTTON** directive, through which I can assign values for **ICON, TEXT and STATE(UI-SREF)**

**HTML template**

```
<v-anc-btn-get state="profile({ id: editor.profileId })" text="Get Profile" icon="fa-book">
</v-anc-btn-get>
```

**DIRECTIVE**

```
function anchorButtonDirective() {
    var directive =
    {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<a class='btn btn-info' ui-sref='ctrl.go()'><i class='fa {{ctrl.icon}}'></i> {{ctrl.text}}</button>",
        scope:
            {
                icon: "@",
                text: "@",
                state: "&"
            },
        controller: function ($state, $stateParams) {
            var ctrl = this;

            ctrl.go = function () {
                return ctrl.state;
            }
        },
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
}
```

Now, the directive throws an error like ***Could not resolve 'go' from state 'xxx.xx'***

What am I doing wrong here?

How do I fix it?? so that I can navigate to the state which I have specified in the directive?

Thanks for the help

**EDIT 1**

Edited as per @DanielC's comments.

Comment: I haven't tested anything yet but you're using var ctrl = this;. but you're just calling go() without the ctrl.go(). Also, your function is changing the state not returning a state. once it's called correctly I think it'll just change the state once loaded. instead I would: return ctrl.state;

Comment: @DanielC - Thanks for your valuable inputs. But, still the problem persists.

Comment: I think you can only pass "editor.profileId" into directive. then construct the state in the directive template.

Comment: @yukuan - Thanks for the suggestion. It was valid one and helpful too. Being a directive, I will using in multiple places and the stateParams values differs for each and every time I use.So, it would be tough to send the stateParams values as you may know the param name.

Comment: I'm working on to put the jsfiddle for the above code. Give me sometime

Answer (score 2):

You could specify which state you want to go to in the `ui-sref` attribute as an expression rather than a calling a function.

It can be done either by binding the ui-sref attribute to the scope variable `ui-sref='{{state}}'` or by calling the controller go function using `ng-click`. You can use `$state` service in your controller function to navigate to the required state by calling the `$state.go` function.

```
var directive =
    {
        restrict: "E",
        template: "<a class='btn btn-info' ng-click='ctrl.go()'><i class='fa {{ctrl.icon}}'></i> {{text}}</button>",
        scope:
            {
                icon: "@",
                text: "@myText",
                state: "@state"
            },
        controller: function ($scope,$state, $stateParams) {
            var ctrl = this;
            ctrl.state = $scope.state;
            ctrl.go = function () {
                $state.go(ctrl.state);
            }
        },
        controllerAs: "ctrl",
        bindToController: true
    };

    return directive;
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/midhunadarvin/npq4uxrc/1/).

Comment: Thanks. Your solution was helpful. But, how do I send the _`stateParams`_ values to the _`ui-sref`_. Being a directive, I would use it in multiple places and also they stateParams values can be _`id`_, _`profileId`_ etc etc. Have to handle these scenarios as well.

Comment: See if this helps : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller