# Passing parameters with ui-router in URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Hi i'm trying to pass a parameter from page A to B.let's say you get a name from user in page A and want to show it in page B.

I Googled a lot but there is not a working result so i can see how all parts work together.

Q :**I know i need to use $stateParams here but how it's unclear for me.**

Thanks is advance.

Comment: you can use `factory` or `$rootScope` for this.

Comment: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/url-routing#url-parameters

Comment: you haven't looked enough.. :P see this question.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Answer (score 2):

Below is an example of state params being used:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.config(function($stateProvider){
  $stateProvider
  .state('sample', {
    url: '/sample/:name',
    templateUrl: '.sampleView.html',
    controller: 'SampleController'
 })

 app.controller('SampleController', function($stateParams) {
   //access params by using $stateParams.<param name>
    var name = $stateParams.name;
 }
```

The scenario you described sounds more like something where you would want to use a factory/service or maybe even some browser caching.