# AngularJS : Pass input parameter in URL with ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller) question and wanted to change it a little so what i enter in `home`'s input field will be shown in the `other`

I tried  bind  the input with `{{name}}`  but don't know how to put it in the line below

```
<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'Foo,mojtaba1', bar: 'barVal1'})">home({foo: 'Foo,mojtaba1', bar: 'barVal1'})</a>
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIwC5Vx9UXUa7jXiC5BP?p=preview) is a plunker

Also added `var name = $stateParams.name;` in `.controller`

So the **question** is how to pass the input name from page `home` to `other` with **url** and also show it?

Comment: in which parameter you wanted to pass `name` parameter?

Comment: it could be a new parameter along side of foo and bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could then add new parameter in your state definition & then pass that parameter in `ui-sref` directive, so that will take care `href` url creation

```
ui-sref="home({foo: 'Foo,mojtaba1', bar: 'barVal1', name: name})"
```