# AngularJs Routing with parameters

Tags: angularjs, routes, ngroute

Can someone explain how I can route to a Url using parameters?

E.g. id like to click on a product and open more info of the product by Id.

My Routing so far ...

```
        angular.module('shop', ["customFilters", "cart", "ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider){

            $routeProvider.when("/complete", {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/orderComplete.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/placeorder", {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/placeOrder.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/checkout", {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/checkoutSummary.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/products", {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/productList.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.when("/product:", {
                templateUrl: "../app/views/product.html"
            });

            $routeProvider.otherwise({
                templateUrl: "../app/views/productList.html"
            });

        });
```

So By clicking ...

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="#/product/{{item.id}}">More Info</a>
```

Id like to be routed to product/{{id}}.html ...

Can someone advise what I am missing in ...

```
       $routeProvider.when("/product:id", {
            templateUrl: "../app/views/product.html"
        });
```

Comment: use https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router

Answer (score 21, accepted):

2 things, but you are basically there.

First you are missing a slash before the URL param. Happens to the best of us.

```
routeProvider.when("/product/:id", {
    templateUrl: "../app/views/product.html"
});
```

Secondly you should use ng-href instead href when you have dynamic URL params.

```
<a ng-href="#/product/{{item.id}}">More Info</a>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, an extra pair of eyes is always the key after hours on coding. Appreciate the help @enzey!

Comment: i have a question, 
what if you have /product/new ... how do you add it?

Answer (score 8):

I thinks this issue is duplicate, see response [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller?answertab=active#tab-top)

you can send paramters to state name as home({foo: 'fooVal1', bar: 'barVal1'})
with a url '/:foo?bar'
see this exemple:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('home', {
      url: '/:foo?bar',
      views: {
        '': {
          templateUrl: 'tpl.home.html',
          controller: 'MainRootCtrl'

        },
        ...
      }
```

and send values as:

```
<a ui-sref="home({foo: 'fooVal1', bar: 'barVal1'})">
```