# 'ui-sref' of Angular UI-Router not working as expected

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

If I am working with href, UI Router works as expected.  But, if I am using ui-sref, it is not working as expected.

I have two issue with the following example:

- the anchors 'link-series-2-no-param' and 'link-series-2-one-param' do not trigger 'otherwise' (they do in 'link-series-1').  What to do if they need to go to 'otherwise'?
- if you click all 'link-series-2' and do the same in reverse, it's not going to work (always shows the result of 'link-series-2-two-params', even if you click on others)

a01.htm:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="a01.js"></script>
...
<a ui-sref='root'>Home</a>
    <br>
    <a href='#/demo1/'>link-series-1-no-param</a>
    <a href='#/demo1/30'>link-series-1-one-param</a>
    <a href='#/demo1/30/40'>link-series-1-two-param</a>
    <br>
    <a ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ui-sref='demo1'>link-series-2-no-param</a>
    <a ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ui-sref='demo1({a: 30})'>link-series-2-one-param</a>
    <a ui-sref-opts="{reload: true, notify: true}" ui-sref='demo1({a: 30, b:40})'>link-series-2-two-param</a>
    <hr>
    <div ui-view></div>
```

a01.JS:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.router']);

app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider
    .state('demo1', {
        url: '/demo1/:a/:b', 
        templateUrl: 'demo1.htm',
        controller: 'demo1'
    })
    .state('root', {
        url: '/',
        template: '<strong>you are at root..click something else</strong>'
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
}]);

app.controller('demo1', ['$scope', '$stateParams', function($scope, $stateParams){
    $scope.a = $stateParams.a;
    $scope.b = $stateParams.b;
    console.log('a = ' + $stateParams.a + ', b = ' + $stateParams.b);
}]);
```

demo1.htm:

```
<div>
    a = {{a}}, b = {{b}}
</div>
```

What am I missing in the above sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour experienced in this case, is coming from a fact that we use an `$state.go` option : **`{ reload: true }`**

```
<a ui-sref-opts="{reload: true ...
```

Check the doc https://ui-router.github.io/docs/0.3.1/#/api/ui.router.state.$state#methods_go

> reload (v0.2.5) - {boolean=false|string|object}, If true will force transition even if no state or params have changed. It will reload the resolves and views of the current state and parent states...

And in [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/yXaSSrWnWD7T2n1M8dZg?p=preview), we can see, that any `ui-sref`, even with missing params, is navigated to... because it was **forced**

But, if we will use the default *(native)* approach, that state is reloaded only if there is any change *(e.g. parameter change)*.

[That example](http://plnkr.co/edit/vmjYD5x7Fz9WR86P4sZ1?p=preview) shows that in action

```
<a ui-sref-opts="{reload: false ...
```

Until any of params is changed - no state change is triggered. Hope that helps a bit...

Comment: Understood.  But, even with "reload:true" and changes in parameters, if we start clicking on all of the 'link-2' series (in an order) and do the same in reverse, the results are inconsistent.

Comment: To be specific, if we click on link-2-series-one-param after link-2-series-two-param (where there is difference in params), it does not reload for link-2-series-one-param

Comment: The point here is - with `$state.go`, i.e. with `ui-sref` we are provided with $stateParams from previous run. So, if value for **:b** was already passed ... and now is missing, it will be still there... reused. If that is a bug, I am not sure. What I would say? Please, do not waste your time here if possible. Try to adjust your app to pass both params into ui-sref. I.e. explicit NULL or -1 ...

Comment: Plase, check this adjusted plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/ERmnRdSO3oXf7U8OzG2U?p=preview with `ui-sref='demo1({a: 30, b: null})'` hope it helps a bit

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/69YrDr8ZsyZCQc4aQoWl?p=preview if you don't want to inherit the existing param values, use `{inherit: false}`