# Trying to pass a ui-sref param dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I amy trying to populate a ui-sref link with a parameter dynamicall:

```
ui-sref="business({id:{{business.busId}}})"
```

But this does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass parameters using ui-sref in ui-router to controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller)

Comment: Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {id:

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate. The issue is the formatting: Error: [$parse:ueoe] Unexpected end of expression: {id:

Answer (score 1):

If you define your state like the following state definition:

```
.state('business', {
  parent: 'dashboard',
  url: '/business/{businessId}',
  controller: 'BusinessController as vm',
  templateUrl: 'business.html'
})
```

Then you can call the state like `<button ui-sref="business({businessId: business.id})"> Click me </button>`

From the a controller you can call the state by calling `$state` like this: `$state.go('business',{businessId: business.id});`

You can read more about [Using Parameters in Links here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-routing)

Answer (score 0):

Have you just tried:

```
ui-sref="business({id: business.busId})"
```