# angular 1 ui router maintaining url param data between states

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with an app on Angular 1 and Ui-router, and I am trying to make so that data in urls will be preserved between states. I have read about the queryParamsHandling:'preserve' feature on Angular 2.0. However I am currently stuck with Angular 1 and I need to resolve how to keep the url data the same between states.

One option I was considering was to preserve the url:params data between states was with the ui-sref, however so far unsuccessful.

Does anyone have good tips how to resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: since you tagged it with `angularjs`, don't assume people will know how `angular` works. It's best to explain what do you want your URL to look like, instead of comparing it to `queryParamsHandling` function. I suggest you look into `$stateParams` or `$transition$.params()` for handling url parameters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller this is proper solution.

Comment: Check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Answer (score 0):

Router File --> route.js:

```
angular
    .module('moduleName')
    .config(['$stateProvider', stateProvider])

function stateProvider($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('lessonDetails', {
            url: '/:lessonId/details',
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: 'lesson/lesson-details.html',
                    controller: 'lessonController'
                }
            }
     });
}
```

HTML file --> lesson-details.html:

```
<a ui-sref="lessonDetails({'lessonId': 123})">Go to details</a>
```

Controller -- > lesson-details.js

```
angular
    .module('moduleName')

    .controller('lessonController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', lessonController]);

     function lessonController($scope, $stateParams){
        //use lessonId passed as params using $stateParams
        console.log($stateParams.lessonId)
     }
```