# Passing dynamic parameter value in ui route

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using UI Router
but I am not able to pass value dynamically
How to pass searchName Dynamically in ui route

```js
.state("search", {
  name: 'search',
  url: '/search/{search}',
  templateUrl: "search-page",
  controller: "searchController"
})


myApp.controller('searchController', function($scope, $http, $stateParams) {
  $scope.searchName = $stateParams.search;
  console.log($scope.searchName);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="search" ng-modal="searchName" name="q"> {{searchName}}
  <div class="input-group-btn">
    <a ui-sref="search({search:searchName})">
      <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25647454/how-to-pass-parameters-using-ui-sref-in-ui-router-to-controller

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xrcwrn/tomLh0v1/  tried here not working

Answer (score 0):

try this and let me know if it works

```
.state('search', {
  name: 'search',
  url: "/search/:search",
  templateUrl: 'search-page',
  controller: function ($stateParams) {
            // If we got here from a url of /search/test54test
    expect($stateParams).toBe({search: "test54test"});
}
```

In your view

```
<a ui-sref="search({search: searchName})">View Contact</a>
```

you can find more by clicking [Here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#url-parameters)